# Removing a blank line of text for loop Java

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops

I am trying to print some timestables using a nested for loop, I got it to work but I have an extra blank line, I was able to remove it using an if statement but I want to know if there is a better way to do this. Output needs to look like this.

> 1 2 3 4 5
>   2 4 6 8 10
>   3 6 9 12 15
>   4 8 12 16 20
>   5 10 15 20 25

```
static void timesTables(){
    for (int i = 1; i <= 2 ; i++){
        for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++){
            int output = i * j;
            System.out.print(output + " ");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the extra blank line showing up? The top or the bottom?  Or maybe somewhere in the middle? Also, is this line showing up on command line or in an IDE console?  Sometimes it looks like there is a new line when there isn't.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't match the output, please post it correctly

Comment: You need as many lines as `i` takes on values. Is there really a problem?

Comment: There seems to be a mismatch between your code and what your are telling here. The code doesn't have an if, nor carriage returns, nor does it produce the output at all (i <= 2)

Comment: code and output does not match, please post complete code here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that output you can add and extra `println`

```
static void timesTables(){
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5 ; i++){
       for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++){
           int output = i * j;
           System.out.print(output + (j < 5)? " ": "");
       }
       System.out.println();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add an extra println with a if condition for your desired output. At the 5th iteration of outer for loop, extra blank line would not be printed.

```
static void timesTables(){
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5 ; i++){
        for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++){
           int output = i * j;
           System.out.print(output + " ");
       }

       if(i<5)
       System.out.println();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to what others have been writing:

```
static void timesTables()
{
    int numRows = 5;
    int numCols = 5;
    for ( int i = 1; i <= numRows; i++ )
    {
         for ( int j = 1; j <= numCols; j++ )
         {
            int output = i * j;
            System.out.print( output + ( j < numCols )? " ": "" );
         }

         if( i < numRows )
         {
            System.out.println();
         }
     }
}
```